# Export 3D DXF elevation line with multiple Z-values to points each with a discrete Z-value

Tags: point, elevation, dxf

We are using a new program that outputs DXF lines with elevation data. I need to compare this data over multiple time-series, but I don't know how to extract it. If I use the identify tool, I can see that all the discrete Z-values are present in the file (closest vertex Z), but I don't know how to extract these values.

I can extract the staring value using "z( start_point( $geometry ))", but I was wondering if there is a way to convert the 3D DXF line into a series of points, each with it's discrete Z-value?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using QGIS since you mentioned you are using this formula:

```
z( start_point( $geometry ))
```

You can use `Extract vertices` tool from Processing toolbox which maintains the z values exist in the line DXF file

Input DXF file (line with Z values (`LineStringZ`))

[image]

Output shapefile (PointZ)

[image]

Then you can export the shafile as DXF file, or you can save the output of Extract vertices tool to DXF file directly if you want, but I didn't test the latter option.

Comment: Thanks very much, and yes, I am using QGIS, although I have ArcGIS too.

I have been using "v.in.dxf" to bring in the file, but it makes a "LineString25D" geometry type. This may be an issue with the dxf I'm importing, or it could be my lack of knowledge on importing these files. What's the best way to import the dxf as a LineStringZ?

Comment: @Blake I just drag and drop DXF file into QGIS. I did not do any trick to open the file or use any plugin. Try importing the DXF from `Add vector layer` and check the layer properties. If it is still `LineString25D`, the it is an issue with your DXF file you are importing.

Comment: Thanks. I worked it out. I just used "Add Geometry Attributes" and the x,y,z coordinates for each point were added to the attributes table!

Thanks again for your wonderful help, and very fast response!

Comment: @Blake Please accept the answer if it helped you so that it can help others.